# How do I handle fixes for bugs, that have not been made part of a version branch?

Tags: yocto

Currently, I work on creating a yocto image for the beaglebone black, using the morty branch. I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.jumpnowtek.com/beaglebone/BeagleBone-Systems-with-Yocto.html), mostly successful. At some point I encountered the following error:

> Fetcher failure for URL: 'http://www.lartmaker.nl/lartware/port/devmem2.c'. Checksum mismatch!
>   File: '/home/user/bbb/downloads/devmem2.c' has md5 checksum e23f236e94be4c429aa1ceac0f01544b when be12c0132a1ae118cbf5e79d98427c1d was expected [...]

I did some research, and found that this problem is known, and fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/commit/6c584374a599f6f8d3607f20ecfc13a67ccf1da1) to the meta-openembedded repo - it occurred because of changes in the devmem2 code.
As the fixing commit was made to the master branch, I decided to override my local morty copy of `devmem2.bb`.
Doing so worked fine, and I was able to download and compile my image from command line using `bitbake qt5-image`.

After doing so, I decided to give [Toaster](https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/Toaster) a go. I added the required layers to a new Toaster project and ran a build of the `qt5-image` (which is part of the meta-bbb layer). However, I ran into the same error as before, as Toaster downloads its own copies of the repositories. I tried doing the same as before, overriding the `devmem2.bb` - without success, as Toaster checks out the current version from the VCS and therefore reverts my changes.

**Now, what I want to know is what would be the correct way of action, or what are my options?**

[Openembedded advises](https://www.openembedded.org/wiki/Dealing_with_checksum_mismatch) to write to the mailing list in cases of checksum errors. But I am hesitant about this, as it is not really an open problem anymore and I don't exactly know what I am doing. But manually overriding recipes is dangerous and feels just plain wrong; even while working.

Obviously, I am still new to yocto and even newer to Toaster, so this problem might be a beginners error (pretty sure, actually).

Comment: Did you make your changes using a .bbappend file? If not, your changes are just overriden. Changes done within bbappend are taken into account after fetching and should not lead to checksum error. Or is not a bitbake error?

Comment: Thank you @guenni_90 you brought me on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recipe `devmem2.bb` in the branch Krogoth is broken because the mirror http://www.lartmaker.nl/lartware/port/devmem2.c is not available.

The cleanest way to fix this issue would be to create another layer.
Copy `meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/devmem2` to `meta-newlayer/recipes-support/devmem2`. 
Rename  `meta-newlayer/recipes-support/devmem2/devmem2.bb` in `devmem2.bbapend` and replace everything inside it by :

```
SUMMARY = "Simple program to read/write from/to any location in memory"
LICENSE = "GPLv2+"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://devmem2.c;endline=28;md5=dd68f2b0a5184b3db3dc25c99e0bd0cd"
PR = "r7"

SRC_URI = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/radii/devmem2/master/devmem2.c \
           file://devmem2-fixups-2.patch;apply=yes;striplevel=0"
S = "${WORKDIR}"

CFLAGS += "-DFORCE_STRICT_ALIGNMENT"

do_compile() {
    ${CC} -o devmem2 devmem2.c ${CFLAGS} ${LDFLAGS}
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install devmem2 ${D}${bindir}
}

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "be12c0132a1ae118cbf5e79d98427c1d"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "ec382c90af3ef2f49695ff14a4d6521e58ac482c4e29d6c9ebca8768f699c191"
```

That fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks Jerome, this is similar to what I ended up doing, except I did not copy the whole meta-oe layer, but created a new one with the bbappend (also a small typo in your answer). Is there any advantage of copying the whole layer? Seems unnecessary.

Comment: The instruction copy meta-openembedded/meta-oe/recipes-support/devmem2 to meta-newlayer/recipes-support/devmem2 doesn't implied to copy the entire meta-oe, only the devmem2 path. Copying the entire  layer is indeed unnecessary.

Comment: I misunderstood that. Your answer is correct. A little hint for others with a similar problem, I found the [yocto-layer](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#creating-a-general-layer-using-the-yocto-layer-script) script really useful for creating the layer. Made things easier and reassured me in my doing. I will use this new layer for all my image additions and changes.